# Possible to store file on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, filesystems

My application needs to download files and store on local file system for future use. I have just 2 questions:

1. Is it possible to write files on iPhone file system?
2. Anyone know how to do it with Unity3D? I tried use the common way to do it (using System.IO), it works both on Windows and Mac but doesn't work on iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Objective-C in Unity3D:

http://www.tinytimgames.com/2010/01/10/the-unityobjective-c-divide/

And here is a tutorial on file IO for iPhone:

http://servin.com/iphone/iPhone-File-IO.html

Comment: Use Object-C is the last option. Better to do it in UnityScript.

Comment: @巫妖王: Ok, just saying, you can mix the two. And then continue using Unity3D script.

Answer (score 0):

1 - Yes, you can use the `writeToFile... atomically...` method in order to write the file to a directory for later use.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, you can. Be sure to check out iOS5 (which is coming soon), you might want to store into the cloud, rather than the device :D

2.I have not tried with Unity3D.